# How to enable/disable compile errors warning in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

In debug mode, if there is an error in our application when we press F5 to start debugging, a dialog appears with the warning: "Your program has an error. Do you want to run your last modified program?" or something like this.

I want to enable or disable this dialog.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is your source code compiling correctly?  Have you checked the Error List output?

Comment: Do you mean the message box that Visual Studio pops up to say there were build errors, do you want to run the last successful build?

Comment: There is a 'remember my answer' check box you can tick if that helps?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can turn that prompt on/off in your Visual Studio settings:

1. From the "Tools" menu, select "Options".
2. In the dialog that appears, expand "Projects and Solutions", and click "Build and Run".
3. On the right side, you'll see a combo box labeled "On Run, when build or deployment errors occur".

   - If you want to disable the message box, select either "Do not launch" or "Launch old version" (which will launch the old version automatically).
   - If you want to enable the message box, select "Prompt to launch" which will ask you each time.

[image: VS "Build and Run" Options]

Of course, as people have suggested in the comments, this means that your code has errors in it somewhere that are preventing it from compiling. You need to use the "Error List" to figure out what those errors are, and then fix them.