# Debugging runs even with compiler's errors in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

When I start debugging a project in Visual Studio 2010 (F5), the applications runs even if there are compiler's errors. Why is this so? How can I repair this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Menu, Tools->Options

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You might have set it to run from the last known successful build.

Look here for more details : [How to enable/disable compile errors warning in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712058/how-to-enable-disable-compile-errors-warning-in-visual-studio/4712123#4712123)

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour is by-design when the project is a Website. Visual Studio will start the web development server even before it ends compilation of all webpages. This happens because a **Website is supposed to compile on demand**, that is when the specific pages are requested. Web applications on the other hand, are precompiled.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple projects in the same solution and the errors are occuring in a project that isn't required by the startup project, then I think the code will launch.