# VS 2012 Starts debugging despite errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio is beginning Debug with code errors on the website being debugged. I threw some gibberish code into a page inside of the site. It gets underlined in red as I'd expect. I then hit "debug" expecting to see "Build errors, do you want to use the last working version?" and it just starts debugging. So I stop debugging, and while the gibberish code is still there, it's no longer underlined in red nor appearing on the Error List tab.

The project is just a Website using ASPX pages, C# code-behind, and the gibberish code was put on the C# code-behind page.

I've followed the directions here: [Debugging runs even with compiler's errors in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814783/debugging-runs-even-with-compilers-errors-in-visual-studio)

As well as here: [How to enable/disable compile errors warning in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712058/how-to-enable-disable-compile-errors-warning-in-visual-studio/)

And neither has helped address this issue.

I also reset my settings to default C# settings as recommended by this link: [Visual Studio Editor does not underline errors anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267843/visual-studio-editor-does-not-underline-errors-anymore)

Yet the issue persists.

These are my build settings pages:

Build Properties Page: [image: Build Properties Page]

Tools/Options/Build and Run: [image: Tools > Options > Build and Run]

It seems I've done everything I should be doing to make this work correctly, am I missing a step?

Comment: What kind of web project? What kind of errors? In which kind of file? ASPX, code-behind, class file?

Comment: The project is just a Website using ASPX pages, C# code-behind, and the gibberish code was put on the C# code-behind page. I'll update the question, thank you.