# Changes to code in Visual Studio 2015 is not executed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, compilation

Even when I comment out code which will crash my program, it still executes. I understand that the last successful build is being executed.

I have seen many posts with this problem like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077899/visual-studio-code-changes-dont-do-anything?noredirect=1). Many of them say the solution is to delete all "bin" and "obj" sub-folders. But I don't know where to find these files. I tried reinstalling Visual Studio 2015 but I still cannot execute my changes to the code.

I have tried to clean / rebuild my code but I get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8UKL.jpg).

[Image of my subfolder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57T9R.png)

Answer (score 0):

They are within your solution folder, example WindowsApplication1. When you create a new project, you are asked for a location on your hard drive. Use search if all else fails

Comment: Could you tell me what is the path or what I can search in cmd? This is what my folder looks like http://imgur.com/a/XOV97

Comment: Search from this location recursively, what's in debug folder?

Comment: I have searched recursively but I cant find anything with a .bin or .obj extension. I have also looked for hidden files. Here's my debug folder http://imgur.com/a/BBYPR

Comment: It's not an extention, it's a folder

Comment: Create a new solution and test your code there. It will be as though you deleted those files

Comment: Sorry I managed to find an obj file here http://imgur.com/a/t5t2i . I deleted it and executed again but the code updates didnt work

Comment: Create a new solution for testing purposes. You need to start fresh.

Comment: And use solution -> clean after deleting anything