# Visual Studio 2022 having to rebuild solution after every change

Tags: c++, build, visual-studio-2022, rebuild

The issue is exactly the same as here: [Visual Studio need to rebuild solution for every change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45688562/visual-studio-need-to-rebuild-solution-for-every-change)

I make a change to my project, press ctrl + shift + b to build and it succeeds. When I go to run my application, the changes I made do not "show". For example, I change some numbers, they don't have any effect. If I put a breakpoint inside a function, it will come up with the same message as in the other post. To apply the changes, I have to click rebuild, which takes around 1 and a half minute to 2 minutes, simply building the changes in a cpp file would take a lot less time. In the configuration manager, I have the project added.

I tried looking inside the project / solution properties, maybe something is set up incorrectly, however, I have found nothing that would cause this.

Comment: what do you change? A cpp file? a header file? are there any warnings in the compiler output? do you have the same file in a project multiple times? are all your header files part of your project?

Comment: I change some code in a cpp file, which would not require a full rebuild. The cpp file is not included in other files, so it should be fine. Let's say, i change a number from 1 to 0, by building it wont take effect, only if i click rebuild, which takes a lot longer.

Comment: At a guess the file is in a project which doesn't have it's dependencies set correctly so it doesn't get built when dependant projects are built

Comment: All of the files are in the same project, and the files do not necessarily rely on other dependencies. The most is, that a header file from the same project is included, however, that header file does not get changed, only the cpp file. Also, this does not happen all the time, just sometimes, hence it's annoying, because I can't know for sure, if it's my code not working, or the code changes just not getting applied.

Comment: From my side, I had this issue when I was including cpp files, technically it is ok to include either cpp or h files, but what I noticed that the changes made to included h files are reflected immediately where the changes made to included cpp files need a rebuild.