# Visual studio 2017 asp.net core project dont accept my changes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017

I'am working on asp.net core project.. After reopened project  ı cant see my changes..

I try add something in codes and build.  But dont accetp my changes.

I adding my changes in code but when I build all changes disappeared.

**ı try this but cant solve problem**
[Visual Studio. Code changes don't do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077899/visual-studio-code-changes-dont-do-anything)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio. Code changes don't do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077899/visual-studio-code-changes-dont-do-anything)

Comment: Not dublicate..I try it..Dont solved..