# Visual Studio 2008 - C# Edits not showing in ASP Intranet Site/App

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

First of all, I am not a C# developer.  Only briefly glanced at it once or twice.  I mainly have worked with VBA for Office and SQL Server for coding.

In my role now, I'm asked to make a correction to an Intranet site/page/tool.  The change (I think) is just a simple text change, which I already made and saved all the files containing the text.  It was literally changing one string to another.

I made the file changes to all the files where the IIS says the app/site is located - where the files are located.

The changes do not show (it seems) in the actual tool/site.

Is there some way I can test it to verify the chagnes aren't actually showing?

Secondly, is there some way I can safely force the site/app to reflect my changes/edits?

I found this former discussion, but was not sure whether any of those suggestions would be relevant to my scenario:
[Visual Studio. Code changes don't do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077899/visual-studio-code-changes-dont-do-anything)

Thanks in advance for any hints or tips.

Comment: What file (aspx or cs) did you change? How is the site deployed (Web Site or precompiled Web Application)?

Comment: Resetting the app pool in IIS may help and should be a safe thing to try.

Comment: What file changed? - Best I recall, all were .cs files

Comment: How deployed?  It's deployed as a page inside an Intranet site..  The Intranet is some Intranet site template from what I can tell

Comment: Thanks for the comments/questions so far.  I looked again at IIS.  In the structure there, this tool is listed as a site underneath "Sites"  There are other unrelated items under Application Pools.  So I am not sure resetting the app pool will help

Comment: Then I would look to see if perhaps publishing has been set up on the project. Go to the web project in the solution, right-click publish and see if there are current settings with that server already listed for deploy.

Comment: I should have posted that - I forgot.  I saw publish before, and tried that.  It wanted to publish to the Document's folder of the logged in user (sounds like a default location rather than specified).  Would I simply point it to where I edited the files, and tell it to publish?

Comment: When I click Publish, looking at the next pop-up window, the first checkbox says "Allow this precompiled site to be updateable."  It's currently checked, not sure if that's a default, or how this site/app is setup or what.  Does that help any?

Comment: In IIS, I do see a "Restart Site" button for the site.  Is that a safe enough thing to try?  Is it possible, that would get things rolling?

Comment: Another note in regards to publishing: It could simply be that the person who edited it in the past did not do so from the same computer I'm using.  I simply found the only copy of Visual Studio I could find on the network (on a server), and used that to take a whack at solving the problem.

Comment: Any other ideas?