# Why doesn't .NET compiler react on changing code?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, compilation

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC web application. To run it, I use the following shell commands:

```
dotnet restore ProjectDirectory
```

and then

```
dotnet run --project ProjectDirectory
```

But I have noticed it doesn't react on changing the code in my project. To check that, I added an `alert` into a script and re-compiled the project. No `alert` was displayed. I also tried adding a label into one of my views. No label.

## What I have tried

1. Checked my code editor (VS Code) really writes changes to the files. I opened the script where I have inserted an `alert` in Notepad. `alert` was there.
2. Re-compiled project three times. No effect.
3. Made some research in the Internet (including Stack Overflow). I couldn't find anyone with the same problem.
4. Now I have asked a question and hope someone can see a possible reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: you need dotnet watch

Comment: Watch? Can you please provide a shell command?

Comment: https://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2021/07/12/aspnetcore6-hot-reload.html

Comment: Didn't help — all the same as when I use simple run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. I have finally found the answer on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077899/visual-studio-code-changes-dont-do-anything). The top answer worked for me.