# How can I disable javascript compile warnings in VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Visual studio seems intent that my javascript code is bad, mostly because it has no knowledge of jquery or some plugins I am using.  Therefore, every time I compile my product it gives me a lot of warnings, most of them are incorrect ($ is not defined, window is not defined, etc...).

I have `/// <reference path="" />` tags setup in my javascript with intellisense working properly so I know these are just not real issues.

How can I disable these warnings?

*edit* to be clear, I need these disabled because it's causing 100+ warnings that are making me lose sight of REAL c# warnings.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712058/how-to-enable-disable-compile-errors-warning-in-visual-studio

Comment: I need to disable the warnings, not what happens when an error happens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the exact same issue you were having: 100s of incorrect errors every save. For me the issue was with Chirpy, which was a prerequisite for another extension. For whatever reason on my end, Chirpy was not in my Extension Manager so it took me a while to find.

Check and see if you have it installed. If so disable JSHint.

1. Tool -> Options
2. Chirpy -> JSHint
3. Uncheck: Run JS Hint

Answer (score 4):

try this and let me know if it works.

Enter the options through Tools > Options.

In the tree to the left, choose Text Editor > JScript > Miscellaneous. Uncheck "Show syntax errors".

Comment: Well that's annoying.  That even turning that off every time I save it still generating the warnings.

Comment: what kind of add-ons do you have installed?  I've noticed some horrible things happening with various add-ons

Comment: I only have the jscript editor extensions (which I uninstalled and still got the issue) and nuget.  Although I didn't try uninstalling then unchecking that option, let me try that.

Comment: Nope, even without jscript editor extensions those options still don't take effect :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a javascript source file on the computer I'm on at the moment to test this, but you may be able to use the #pragma command to disable particular warnings:

`#pragma warning disable` will disable all warnings, and `#pragma warning restore` will restore all warnings when placed at the end of your code block.  You can also tell it to disable only particular warnings, such as `#pragma warning disable 0219,0168`.

http://abhijitjana.net/2010/08/27/how-to-suppress-complier-warning-using-pragma-warning-directives-in-visual-studio/

Comment: If I put that in the javascript though my javascript will have errors

Comment: I thought that might be the case.  :-(

Comment: Just reviewing my answer, and I think you could get around the JavaScript errors by encasing the #pragma in a JavaScript comment block before and after the #pragma line.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting I am not able to reproduce your issue in neither VS2010 "website" project nor vs2010 "web application" project. It has to do with the add-ons that you installed. Probably you may have a setting in that add-on (who ever is causing this) to disable warnings.

To me the warning sounds like the add-on (who ever is causing this) is not intelligent enough. Try the below changes and see if that helps.

1. If you have master page then try move the jquery*.js script reference from master page to your actual page
2. Move all your javascript code into a js file instead of writing it them under script tag

Thanks,

Esen

Answer (score 0):

What about this one?

> To disable a single compiler warning

```
With a project selected in Solution Explorer, on the Project menu, click Properties.

Click the Compile tab.

In the Warning configurations table, set the Notification value for the warning to None.
```

or perhaps this one

> Tools > Options > Text Editor > JScript > Misc > Show errors as warnings( uncheck only this )