# Visual Studio database project ignore error when publishing

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, compiler-errors, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

I have been trying to deploy my one of database project and I'm receiving few errors like linked server couldn't find etc. But those errors are OK and I want to continue with deployment.

So is there anyway to ignore any deployment errors?

Note that my project is building successfully

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4712123/2118383)

> You can turn that prompt on/off in your Visual Studio settings:
>
> 1. From the "Tools" menu, select "Options".
> 2. In the dialog that appears, expand "Projects and Solutions", and click "Build and Run".
> 3. On the right side, you'll see a combo box labeled "On Run, when build or deployment errors occur".
>
>    - If you want to disable the message box, select either "Do not launch" or "Launch old version" (which will launch the old version
>        automatically).
>    - If you want to enable the message box, select "Prompt to launch" which will ask you each time.
>
> [image: VS "Build and Run" Options]
>
> Of course, as people have suggested in the comments, this means that
>   your code has errors in it somewhere that are preventing it from
>   compiling. You need to use the "Error List" to figure out what those
>   errors are, and then fix them.

Comment: i did as exactly @vignesh mentioned, but still receiving same error.